# Why $rI\subset I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following text is from the book Abstract Algebra by T. W. Judson :

[image]

Why $rI\subset I$ (in underlined sentence)?

Clear simple explanation would much be appreciated.

Comment: because it's an important property that ideals absorb products?  ..maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: Recall that an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ is an abelian subgroup of $R$ such that for all $r\in R$, and all $a\in I$, we have $ra\in I$. The set $rI$ consists of elements $ra$ with $a\in I$. Since $I$ is an ideal  $ra\in I$, hence $rI\subset I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in I$; then $x=sa+m$ for some $s\in R$ and $m\in M$, so $rx=r(sa+m)=(rs)a+rm$. Now $rs\in R$, and since $M$ is an ideal, $rm\in M$, so $rx\in I$: it’s a multiple of $a$ plus something in $M$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $I$, this shows that $rI\subseteq I$.

Comment: O Yes! "since M is an ideal" solved my question; thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @L.G.: You’re welcome, and thanks for catching the typo.